# SystemVerilog program block vs. traditional testbench

Tags: unit-testing, testing, verilog, system-verilog

Are there any features of SV that a program block offers that can't be duplicated with other methods?

The less concrete version of this question is: should I bother with program blocks for verification? I'm moving from an environment where we were constrained to Verilog-95 to an environment where SV is supported, and I'm wondering if I'm creating extra work for myself by not using program blocks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 3.4 & § 24. For full description about `program` blocks.

In a short, incomplete summary, a `program` block:

- cannot cannot contain `always` procedures, `primitive` instances, `module`
  instances, `interface` instances (`virtual interface` and port `interface` is allowed), or other `program` instances.
- specifies scheduling in the Reactive region. This prevents race conditions.
- has an extra system task `$exit`, which terminates the `program` instances that calls it.

  - The simulation will terminate when all `program` instances have exited.
- is mostly like a `module` block except as stated above.

The idea of a `program` block is to create a clear separation between test and design. In earlier versions of SystemVerilog (pre IEEE 1800), instantiation of a `class` was often limited to `program` blocks. This emphasized the division of test and design. It also made `program` blocks vital for verification engineers that that wanted to use object orientated programming in their flow. Since IEEE 1800, a `class` can be defined and instantiated almost anywhere. As a result, `program` blocks became less sufficient.

Today the opinion of usefulness of a `program` block is divided. From the last few conventions I been to, the trend seems to be in favor of abandoning `program` blocks. This is because the advantages can be achieved by other methods. Scheduling in the Reactive region can be done with `clocking` blocks. A `mailbox`, queue(`[$]`), or associative array (`[*]`) can be used for intelligently handling simulation terminate running multiple tests. Personally, I still like using `program` blocks and use `initial forever` as an `always` equivalent when needed. If you are planning to use UVM, then a non-`program` blocks test bench might work better for you.

In the end, it really comes down to a methodology preference. It is best to evaluate and try it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using program blocks - use a module instead. I wrote a [detailed article](http://go.mentor.com/programblocks) about this several years ago.